# Importing phone contacts doesn't import google contacts saved in local database android

Tags: android, google-contacts-api

I want to fetch the phone contacts, SIM contacts and Google contacts saved in my phone but I am getting only phone and SIM contacts. If I can access the Google contacts offline it must be stored in the local database somewhere.

How can I import all of them? I have searched everywhere but couldnt find a solution.

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
//fetching contacts from phone

    contacts_fetched = false;
    contacts_refreshed=false;

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //phoneContactName.add(name);

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).trim();
                    //getting present country code of mobile
                    GetCountryZipCode(phoneNo);
                    if (CountryZipCode != null) {

                        if (phoneNo.contains("+")) {
                            phoneContactNos.add(phoneNo);
                            //Toast.makeText(this, phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            //adding country code if not present
                            phoneNo = CountryZipCode + " " + phoneNo;
                            phoneContactNos.add(phoneNo);
                            //Toast.makeText(this, phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                        phoneContactName.add(name);
                    }
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
//importing contacts from sim
      Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
    Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri,null,null,null,null);

  while (cursorSim.moveToNext())
    {
         simContactName=cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name"));
        simContactNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number"));
        simContactNo.replaceAll("\\D","");
        simContactNo.replaceAll("&", "");
        simContactName=simContactName.replace("|","");
        System.out.println("SimContacts"+simContactName);
        System.out.println("SimContactsNo"+simContactNo);
        if(!phoneContactNos.contains(simContactNo))
        {
            GetCountryZipCode(simContactNo);
            if (CountryZipCode != null) {

                if (simContactNo.contains("+")) {
                    phoneContactNos.add(simContactNo);
                    phoneContactName.add(simContactName);
                    //Toast.makeText(this, phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    //adding country code if not present
                    simContactNo = CountryZipCode + " " + simContactNo;
                    phoneContactNos.add(simContactNo);
                    //Toast.makeText(this, phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Sim Contact Name: " + simContactName);
                Log.i(TAG, "Sim Phone Number: " + simContactNo);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the [People](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started) API is meanwhile the suggested method - compared to the previous [Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) API:

> For read and write access to users' contacts, use the People API, which provides both contact and profile information using JSON instead of the older GData protocol.

instead of a code example, here's the Java [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java) & [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/).

the dependency for the `build.gradle` should be:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev187-1.23.0'
}
```

by the way, this is no `CountryZipCode` - but a country (entry) code.

Comment: that CountryZipCode method is working to fetch the present country code of the android device.Can u please post a sample code for using People API?

Comment: @user8601021 just see the quickstart, that is the sample code... while ZIP (Zone Improvement Plan) codes are barely used for postal delivery, not telephony networks. I mean, when giving variables such strange names, this does not necessarily make life any easier - while it even semantically collides with https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/model/Address.html#getPostalCode().

Comment: only the  method name getCountryZipCode is incorrect.it does what i want ie...getting device's country code

Comment: @user8601021 just see the fields of the people model... wrongful variable/method names just cause a mess, once dealing with more than one data model. countries also do not have ZIP codes, ZIP codes are US postal codes. most likely you will have to convert all into the same type of POJO & possibly remember the data source (SIM, Phone, Google).

Comment: thanks Martin I will correct the method name to just getCountryCode